# java coding to find 20 frquently used words across files

Tags: java

iam writing this code to find the top 20 frequently used words across files i have read
    but am getting error as null point exception in line 51 and 20
    and am unable to find it
    what changes do i need 
to make
    iam reading files based on command line arguments
Also provide me some help to add conditions
Thank you in advance.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class WordFrequency {
    private static final Hashtable<String, Integer> Null = null;    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("in to the main");
        WordFrequency test = new WordFrequency();
        test.countWordFre(args); // for accessing the countWordFre method
    }

    // countWordFre method      
    public void countWordFre(String[] fileNames) throws IOException {

        int i;

        Scanner fileReader = null;

        Hashtable<String, Integer> map = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

        System.out.println("reading files");

        System.out.println("enter how many number of files to read");
        System.out.println(" enter the filename");

        // as command line arguments

        for ( i = 0 ; i < fileNames.length ; i++ ) {

            fileReader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileNames [i]));
        }


        while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = fileReader.nextLine();

            String word;
            // to read each tokens of a line

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);


            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                word = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();

                System.out.println("converting the words to lower case");   


                if (map.containsKey(word)) {

                    int count = (Integer) map.get(word);

                    map.put(word, count + 1);

                } else {

                    map.put(word, 1);

                }

            }

        }

        Enumeration<String> e = map.keys();

        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

            String word = e.nextElement();

            System.out.println(word + " " + map.get(word));
        } 
    }
   // System.out.println(map.size());




    public void List() throws IOException

    {

        System.out.println("to find 20 frq word");


        Hashtable<String, Integer> map = Null;



        List<String> mapKeys = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<Integer> mapValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());  


        Collections.sort(mapValues);
        Collections.reverse(mapValues); //descending order sort
        Collections.sort(mapKeys);
        Collections.reverse(mapValues);

        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(); 

        Iterator<Integer> valueIt = mapValues.iterator();

        while (valueIt.hasNext()) {

            Object val = valueIt.next();


            Iterator<String> keyIt = mapKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIt.hasNext()) {

               Object key = keyIt.next();

               String valueFromOriginalMap = map.get(key).toString();

               String valueFromCurrentIteration = val.toString();

               if (valueFromOriginalMap .equals(valueFromCurrentIteration )) {                                                 

                    map.remove(key);                                                    
                    mapKeys.remove(key);                                             
                    sortedMap.put((String)key , (Integer)val);

                    break;
               }       


           }

     }

  }

}
```

Comment: I just spend 10 minutes trying to reformat your code... so I will not help you. And please, indicate what is the lines 20 and 51 since it's not the same line number here. And copy/paste exception.

Comment: Would you mind telling us what is your program's line no. 20 and 51!

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are not passing arguments to your program properly, i get the same error without args. With correct args it runs fine.

Make sure to pass arguments properly in cmd

```
java WordFrequency "Hello.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing a much smaller and simpler program to 1) Read in a filename from the console. 2) Open that file as text. 3) Display the first 20 words of the file on the screen.

Test that smaller program thoroughly to make sure it works.  For example, what does it do if you make an error typing the filename?  Say, "myfile.**ttx**" instead of "myfile.txt"

When you have the smaller program working, then expand it to count the 20 most common words in a single file.  Again test and fix any problems.  Only then try to write your final program to count words across multiple files.

Getting that first small program to work should show you where your current program is failing, but it will be easier to see because the program is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
    for ( i = 0 ; i < fileNames.length ; i++ ) {
        fileReader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileNames [i]));
    }
    while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
```

will only handle the last file with the overwritten variable `fileReader`.

In general it pays having the declaration as close to its usage, declare-on-first-use.

Checks on the input, like printing the file handled might help too.

The NullPointerException might disappear with correct structure and checked input data.

BTW you might do:

```
            Integer freq = map.get(word);
            int count = freq == null ? 0 : freq;
            map.put(word, count + 1);
```